# Create a normal Django Model, View, Serializer within a wagtail app

Tags: django, wagtail

We currently have a wagtail app that acts like a CMS as it should, but we recently had a requirement that requires us to create a model view and serializer that should not be seen through wagtail admin page.

I've gone through and created a model from within one of our apps in django (not from home apps that is default created by wagtail).

```
class MasterClass(models.Model):
      topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      <<redacted>>
```

and it doesnt seem to be detected by django when doing make migrations.

is there any additional config to make this work?

Comment: surprisingly stuck on same problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the app that contains the new model is listed in the INSTALLED_APPS of your settings.py.
2. Check if the app containing the new model has a models.py file in its directory.

Then try to run `./manage.py makemigrations` again.

Also make sure that the name of your app is not the same as a built-in Django app or a third-party app. Finally check the syntax `<<redacted>>`. Doesn't it raise a syntax error? If it does, then probably it is the reason why `makemigrations` doesn't work properly.